# Vertical scroll bar to one column of each row of the table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table in a html5. One of the columns is a description column. And since I am using bootstrap class `"col-md-2"`. The description being long goes a lot down. I want to enable a vertical scroll for that particular `<td>`. I have tried using `style="overflow-y: auto;"` with td. But, it doesn't seem to work.

HTML File :

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table ng-if="applicationListAdmin" st-table="applicationTable" class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Application No.</th>
            <th>Project Title</th>
            <th>Project Description</th>
            <!-- <th>DataSet Available</th> -->
            <!-- <th>Impact</th> -->
            <th>Number of Interns</th>
            <th>Expected SkillSet</th>
            <th>Software Licenses Needed</th>
            <th>Hardware Requirements</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Update</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="application in applicationListAdmin">

                <td class="col-md-2">{{application.number}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">{{application.title}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2" style="overflow-y: auto;">{{application.description}}</td>

                <td class="col-md-1">{{application.numberOfInterns}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">{{application.skillSet}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">{{application.software}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">{{application.hardware}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">{{application.state}}</td>

                <td>
                    <i class="material-icons" ng-click="view(application._id)">receipt</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <i class="material-icons" ng-click='edit(application._id)' style="color:red">edit</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <i class="material-icons" ng-click="remove(application._id)" style="color:red">delete</i>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Css values for table:

```
th,td {
    /*border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #BCBCBC;*/
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Where is other CSS? Just overflow:auto will not work

Comment: @KK - I have added the css for table, excuse for not adding it earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the height to the table td. but what you can do is put the contents inside a div and place that div inside the td

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        div{
          overflow-y:scroll;
          height:100px !important;
        }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Description</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td >
          March
        </td>
    <td >
     <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing    elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
          </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For scroll to appear, you need to set the height on the element.
Try:

```
    <td class="col-md-2" style="overflow-y: auto;height: 100px;display:block;">random text</td>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2165/